# Proper place to perform POSTS in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would one use services or controllers for POSTing data to a server? The way iv'e seen most examples are people using factory's to GET data from a server. Right now my I have 2 factories one for getting customers and one for getting todo lists. I'd like to have something to post customers and todo's. But unsure where the proper place would be to put it.

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
    factory('Todos', function($http){
        var Todos = {};
        $http.get('/api/todos')
            .success(function(data) {
                Todos.data = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        return Todos;
    })
    .factory('Customers', function($http){
        var Customers = {};
        $http.get('/api/customer')
            .success(function(data) {
                Customers.data = data;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('error: ' + data);
            });
        return Customers;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are a right place for all kind of requests, not only GET and POST. You could perform DELETE or PUT requests here by example.
Doing them all in services will help you to keep you code base consistant so it will increase it's maintainability (although you should consider splitting your service in several thematic files if your codebase grows).

It will also allow you to share them between controllers if needed.

Last but not least, you should look at the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) factory; it could dramatically reduce the amount of code you have to write in services.